# php getopt is returning empty array

Tags: php

I am trying to get options from PHP7 cli with `getopt()`, but I get an empty array when calling `php myprocess.php task -d -o`. No idea what I am missing, hope you can help me.

This is how I am reading options:

```
$options = getopt("d::o::");
```

Thanks

Comment: Move `task` to the end of command `php myprocess.php -d -o task`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As manual said

> The parsing of options will end at the first non-option found, anything that follows is discarded.

So, `t` in "task" is "first non-option found" that's why anything that follows (including `-d` and `-o`) is discarded.

So, you either move `task` to the end of shell call:

```
> php myprocess.php -d -o task
```

Or set a task as an option too:

```
$options = getopt("d::o::t::");   // added `t` option
echo'<pre>',print_r($options),'</pre>';

> php myprocess.php -d -o -ttask
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [d] => 
    [o] => 
    [t] => task
)
```